# How to get top 1 row for each of the state in USA

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a list of states in table 1 (Statename, StateAbbreviation)
I have different city based records having StateAbbreviations in table 2

I want top 1 record per state from table 2

My result should contain one record for each of the states in table 1

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` and `PARTITION BY` StateAbbreviation to obtain the first city per state:

```
WITH d
AS
(
    SELECT StateAbbreviation, CityName
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
          (
           PARTITION BY StateAbbreviation 
               ORDER BY CityName
          ) AS Ordinal
      FROM dbo.Cities
)
SELECT d.StateAbbreviation, StateName, CityName
  FROM d
  JOIN dbo.States AS s
    ON s.StateAbbreviation = d.StateAbbreviation
 WHERE Ordinal = 1;
```

You can change the `ORDER BY` clause to whatever suits your requirement but the key here is to make sure that you partition by the `StateAbbreviation` to get the row number generated per state.